# How do i format time into seconds in lua?

Tags: date, time, lua

So basically I'm confused on how I'd make it so that I can convert DD:HH:MM:SS to only seconds while taking into account the amount of numbers there are. (Sorry if I make 0 sense, you should definitely know what I mean by the example below.)

```
print("05:00":FormatToSeconds()) -- 5 minutes and 0 seconds
-- 300

print("10:30:15":FormatToSeconds()) -- 10 hours, 30 minutes and 15 seconds
-- 37815

print("1:00:00:00":FormatToSeconds()) -- 1 day
-- 86400

print("10:00:00:30":FormatToSeconds()) -- 10 days, 30 seconds
-- 864030
```

So on and so forth. I think that maybe using gmatch would work but still idk. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

So I've tried doing it with gmatch, but I don't know if this is the most fastest way of doing this (which it probably isn't), so any help would still be appreciated.

(My code)

```
function ConvertTimeToSeconds(Time)
    local Thingy = {}
    local TimeInSeconds = 0
    
    for v in string.gmatch(Time, "%d+") do
        if tonumber(string.sub(v, 1, 1)) == 0 then
            table.insert(Thingy, tonumber(string.sub(v, 2, 2)))
        else
            table.insert(Thingy, tonumber(v))
        end
    end
    
    if #Thingy == 1 then
        TimeInSeconds = TimeInSeconds + Thingy[1]
    elseif #Thingy == 2 then
        TimeInSeconds = TimeInSeconds + (Thingy[1] * 60) + Thingy[2]
    elseif #Thingy == 3 then
        TimeInSeconds = TimeInSeconds + (Thingy[1] * 60 * 60) + (Thingy[2] * 60) + Thingy[3]
    elseif #Thingy == 4 then
        TimeInSeconds = TimeInSeconds + (Thingy[1] * 24 * 60 * 60) + (Thingy[2] * 60 * 60) + (Thingy[3] * 60) + Thingy[4]
    end
    
    return TimeInSeconds
end

print(ConvertTimeToSeconds("1:00:00:00"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry about execution speed before doing any actual measurements unless you're designing a time-critical program. In any extreme situation you'd probably want to offload risky parts to a C module.

Your approach is just fine. There are parts you can clean up: you can just return the results of calculations as `TimeInSeconds` doesn't actually act as accumulator in your case; `tonumber` handles `'00'` just fine and it can ensure decimal integers with an argument (since 5.3).

I'd go the other way and describe factors in a table:

```lua
local Factors = {1, 60, 60 * 60, 60 * 60 * 24}
local
function ConvertTimeToSeconds(Time)
  local Components = {}
  for v in string.gmatch(Time, "%d+") do
    table.insert(Components, 1, tonumber(v, 10))
  end
  if #Components > #Factors then
    error("unexpected time component")
  end
  local TimeInSeconds = 0
  for i, v in ipairs(Components) do
    TimeInSeconds = TimeInSeconds + v * Factors[i]
  end
  return TimeInSeconds
end
```

Of course, both implementations have problem with pattern being naïve as it would match e.g., `'00 what 10 ever 10'`. To fix that, you could go another route of using `string.match` with e.g., `'(%d+):(%d+):(%d+):(%d+)'` and enforcing strict format, or matching each possible variant.

Otherwise you can go all in and use [LPeg](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/%7Eroberto/lpeg/) to parse the duration.

Another way would be to not use strings internally, but instead convert them into a table like `{secs=10, mins=1, hours=10, days=1}` and then use these tables instead - getting seconds from that representation would be straight-forward.